# Deploy Tomcat using Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment

I want to deploy the tomcat on production and jar on non-embedded tomcat using Maven. I have added Tomcat7 Maven Plugin in POM.XML but running mvn tomcat7:run runs the application on embedded tomcat.

Can anyone explain, how to deploy and run application on non-embedded tomcat using maven. And as i am new in tomcat, maven and java, could anyone please explain what is embedded tomcat for?

Comment: When you do a maven-build, if you are getting your jar file inside "target" folder, you can deploy that jar file inside tomcat, non-embedded one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your pom.xml must have this configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/MyWebApp</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

%TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="user" password="password" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

%MAVEN_HOME%/conf/settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

Having done this, use the command `tomcat7:deploy` or `tomcat7:redeploy`

More documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat6-maven-plugin/redeploy-mojo.html)